# R - put ggplot grid lines in foreground

Tags: r, ggplot2, themes, r-grid

I would like to know if there is a way to let ggplot draw its grid lines in front of the plotted data. As far as I know, I can format almost everything easily by using theme() which works well so far. However, I don't find the option in which order the elements are drawn. I could introduce additional lines to the plot which need to be formatted (coordinates, line groups, etc.) beforehand. Sounds more complicated as it need to be. So I hope, I can modify the plot-grid itself to do the job.

An example of how I am usually plotting the data frame `sf.df` of the loaded shapefile `sf`:

```
(ggplot(sf.df, aes(x=long, y=lat))
+ geom_polygon(data=sf.df, aes(group=group, fill=NFK))
+ theme(panel.grid.major=element_line(colour="black"))
+ coord_map(xlim=c(7.08, 7.14), ylim=c(50.93, 50.96))
)
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You aren't going to be able to do this via `theme`. I would think you'd just need two extra geom's, one `geom_hline` and one `geom_vline`.

Comment: Ok, I have to rely on these both then. They work well when everything is set up in a self-made plotting function. The ticks have to be adjusted accpordingly and the grid in background must be invisible. Thank you for pointing me in the seemingly least painful direction :)

Comment: This question already has an anwser here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33989595/overlay-grid-rather-than-draw-on-top-of-it/   ; basically: `theme(panel.ontop=TRUE, panel.background = element_rect(fill = NA))`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As @joran suggested, using `geom_hline` and `geom_vline` is defenitely a solution. Simple define the `yintercept` and `xintercept` respectively like so:

```
...
+ geom_vline(xintercept=seq(7.08, 7.14, by=0.01))
+ geom_hline(yintercept=seq(50.93, 50.96, by=0.01))
...
```