# How to draw grid on top of one geom but not another

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a ggplot2 plot seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/76h1m.png)

```
library(ggridges)
library(tidyverse)

ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Species)) + 
  geom_rect(xmin = 4, xmax = 7, ymin = 1, ymax = 6,
            fill = '#d6d6d6') +
  geom_density_ridges() +
  theme_ridges()
```

How can I make it so that the grid is drawn on top of my geom_rect but not my geom_density_ridge? I have seen the ability to place the grid on top of **all** data referenced [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33989595/overlay-grid-rather-than-draw-on-top-of-it)

with `+ theme( panel.background = element_rect(fill = NA), panel.ontop = TRUE )`

But what I really want is for it to be **in-between** the geoms

Comment: @RicardoSemiãoeCastro `iris` is a built-in data set in R

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't really possible to move the panel grid over some geoms but not others (at least not without rendering the ggplot and hacking the underlying grobs).

However, the obvious workaround is to make the grid with `hline` and `vline` geoms:

```r
library(ggridges)
library(tidyverse)

ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Species)) + 
  geom_rect(xmin = 4, xmax = 7, ymin = 1, ymax = 6,
            fill = '#d6d6d6') +
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept = Species), color = "gray70") +
  geom_vline(data = data.frame(Sepal.Length = 4:8),
                               aes(xintercept = Sepal.Length),
             color = "gray70") +
  geom_density_ridges() +
  theme_ridges()
```

[image]